# LINQ: get sum of a column using joins

Tags: c#, linq, join, sum

I have a join query which I want to use in c#.. I want to know How can I get a sum of particular column in a var.? in my query I want sum of earnings column which is in checks table..

```
SELECT SUM(Earnings) FROM [Customers0].[pay].[Checks] AS C
INNER JOIN [Customers0].[pay].[CheckVendorCalc] AS CV ON C.CheckID=CV.CheckID
INNER JOIN [Customers0].[pay].[Vendor] AS V ON CV.VendorID=V.VendorID
WHERE 
C.CustomerID = 360 and 
V.EPVendorWLID = 156 and 
CV.Earnings <> 0 and
C.CheckDate >= '01-01-2022' and C.checkdate <= '12-31-2022'
```

I have tried to implement same in c#..I am not getting any error using this LINQ, I am not sure if this correct to get sum of earnings column.

```
var joinResult = (from c in db.Checks
                          join cv in db.CheckVendorCalcs on c.CheckID equals cv.CheckID
                          join v in db.Vendors on cv.VendorID equals v.VendorID
                          where ( c.CustomerID==CustomerID && v.EPVendorWLID==VendorWLID && v.EffDate==effectiveDate)
                          select new { Earnings= cv.Earnings}
                          
                         );
```

Comment: how is this question related to **vb.net**?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.Sum()` after `IQueryable` to calculate the total of `Earnings`.

```cs
var joinResult = (from c in db.Checks
                  join cv in db.CheckVendorCalcs on c.CheckID equals cv.CheckID
                  join v in db.Vendors on cv.VendorID equals v.VendorID
                  where ( c.CustomerID == CustomerID && v.EPVendorWLID == VendorWLID && v.EffDate == effectiveDate)
                  select new { Earnings = cv.Earnings } 
                 )
    .Sum(x => x.Earnings);
```

---

You can modify your query to return only `Earnings` instead of an anonymous type.

```cs
var joinResult = (from c in db.Checks
                  join cv in db.CheckVendorCalcs on c.CheckID equals cv.CheckID
                  join v in db.Vendors on cv.VendorID equals v.VendorID
                  where ( c.CustomerID == CustomerID && v.EPVendorWLID == VendorWLID && v.EffDate == effectiveDate)
                  select cv.Earnings
                 )
    .Sum();
```